# Can I get a North Korea stamp in my passport?

Tags: passport-stamps, north-korea

A Google search will show that North Korea usually issues a visa on a separate piece of paper, not as a stamp or sticker in your passport. But suppose I really do want one; I like having all the records in my passport and not have a random outlier.

This [TripAdvior topic](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294443-i9734-k8321869-Any_travel_issues_due_to_a_NK_stamp_in_your_passport-North_Korea.html) has a few responses with respect to a UK citizen:

> You will only get a stamp in your passport for NK if you go to the NK embassy in London and pay £20 to get an actual stamp - otherwise it's a paper visa that isn't attached to your passport.

and

> Absolutely no issues at all. I have the whole visa and stamp in my passport and no one bats an eyelid, or if they can read Korean, they just get curious to see a visa that is not commonly seen.

When I browse the web, all I find are a scarce number of messages like those above. So my question is, are there any ways to **guarantee** or **improve the likelihood** of receiving a stamp/visa in my passport with clear steps to follow?

**FYI:**
I am an American citizen. I know there is currently a travel ban (unless applied for special permission), but I am interested in gathering knowledge on what does/did work anyway.

Comment: "assume the travel ban is lifted" - why? Your government has specifically banned you from travelling to North Korea without special permission. Your chances of getting any sort of NK visa are precisely nil. What will happen when (if) the ban is lifted is anybody's guess.

Comment: Because someone may have a valid answer proven to work before the travel ban that continues to work after it expires. My point is I want to gather knowledge of recent ways others may have done this and not just an answer respective to this exact moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mainly group visas issued in Beijing that are loose-leaf documents, while visas from North Korean embassies are pasted in the person's passport.

If the visa's in your passport, the entry and exit stamps will be as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to depend.  Some people have had an experience where you get it on a separate piece of paper, that you keep with your passport.

Others have it glued into their passport and would not be able to remove it without damaging their passport itself.  For example, an answer [from quora](https://www.quora.com/Will-a-North-Korea-visa-stamp-on-my-passport-make-me-unable-to-visit-or-obtain-visas-for-any-other-country-afterwards) shows it glued into a Dutch passport after his visit.